# Webrtc adding ice candidate to remote peer

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

Below is the sample webrtc peer to peer connection code  from google webrtc tutorilal. [this link.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#4) I couldn't understand properly ,how addIceCandidate() add its Ice candidate to its remote peer using onIceCandidate(). what does event.candidate means here. A clear explanation would be appreciated

```
function onIceCandidate(pc, event) {   //pc1.onicecandidate
  if (event.candidate) {
    getOtherPc(pc).addIceCandidate(
      new RTCIceCandidate(event.candidate)
    ).then(
      function() {
        onAddIceCandidateSuccess(pc);
      },
      function(err) {
        onAddIceCandidateError(pc, err);
      }
    );
```

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/ explains what an ice candidate is (along with many other concepts needed to understand things)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When peer A has discovered an ICE candidate (a potential route which could be used to communicate), it needs to send this ICE candidate to peer B (and vice versa). Peer B then adds that ICE candidate to its connection. Both peers exchange ICE candidates this way until they have found the optimal route that both are able to use to communicate with each other directly.

In that simple sample, peer A and B seem to be in the same machine, so the (dummy) `getOtherPc` function can get a handle of "the other peer" and you can directly use its `addIceCandidate` method. In practice however you will have to send that ICE candidate using a *signalling server*; some other way in which the peer can exchange the information across a network. Typically that signalling server will use a websocket connection via which information can be relayed in near-realtime.

Comment: let's say client A and B access the same web server where the web application is hosted. The `onicecandidate` gets called even at the `have-local-offer` state. Is this possible? I was thinking `icecandidate` event will be triggered after `have-remote-pranswer` (i.e. `stable`)

Comment: Yes, off the top of my head, ICE candidate gathering begins as soon as you set a local description. In fact, every ICE candidate becomes part of the local description, and you can wait until ICE gathering has completed and then simply send the complete local description including ICE candidates. If you send ICE candidates one by one, that's called *ICE trickling* and is optional behaviour.

Comment: I came across an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198751/domexception-error-processing-ice-candidate), saying you could only add ice candidates after remote description is set. how true is this?

Comment: Well, you will *discover* ICE candidates as soon as you have your own local description. You then send that candidate to the remote peer B. *That peer* can only set it (add it to your, peer A's, session description), when it has peer A's session description. Again, think of ICE candidates as belonging to the SDP, which in fact they do if you wait long enough as described above. Receiving ICE candidates separately later and adding them is just amending the remote SDP after the fact.